# Create new rows based on condition of previous rows in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset as follows

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 2, 2), enrollment = c(2014, 2011, 
2012, 2013), deregister = c(2016, 9999, 9999, 9999)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

I need to convert that dataset to the following one:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), enrollment = c(2014, 
2015, 2016, 2011, 2012, 2013), deregister = c(9999, 9999, 2016, 
9999, 9999, 9999)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

The idea is: if deregister is not 9999, add a new row to dataset by adding 1 to the enrollment untill enrollment=degister. Encode newly added row's deregisters with 9999 until enrollment=degister.

Since I have a lot of observations, I want to create dataset without loops.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mapply` + `:` to create the sequences:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(enrollment = ifelse(deregister != 9999, mapply(`:`, enrollment, deregister), enrollment)) %>% 
  unnest_longer(enrollment) %>% 
  mutate(deregister = replace(deregister, enrollment != deregister, 9999))

#   id enrollment deregister
# 1  1       2014       9999
# 2  1       2015       9999
# 3  1       2016       2016
# 4  2       2011       9999
# 5  2       2012       9999
# 6  2       2013       9999
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative appraoch. Could you please check whether this will work for your original dataset:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

  df %>%
    mutate(value = ifelse(deregister != 9999,
                          enrollment + 1,
                          0)) %>% 
    pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "name", values_to = "enrollment") %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    arrange(enrollment, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
    mutate(deregister = ifelse(name=="deregister" & enrollment!=9999, enrollment, 9999)) %>% 
    filter(enrollment != 9999 & enrollment != 0) %>% 
    select(-name) %>% 
    ungroup()
```

```
    id enrollment deregister
  <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1       2014       9999
2     1       2015       9999
3     1       2016       2016
4     2       2011       9999
5     2       2012       9999
6     2       2013       9999
```